# How can I generate 'un-mappable' input for a Java CharsetDecoder?

Tags: java, text, character-encoding, nio

I'm writing a set of unit tests for a text decoding class. I'd like to write a test that correctly exercises the handling of un-mappable *input* to a `CharsetDecoder`. However, I've struggle to initiate a byte buffer that does this. Example:

```
CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("utf-8").newDecoder();
decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
ByteBuffer in = ?
CharBuffer out = CharBuffer.allocate(256);
CoderResult result = decoder.decode(in, out, true);
assertTrue(result.isUnmappable());
```

**How can I initiate the byte buffer (line 3) to pass the assertion (line 6)?**

---

Things that don't work:

- NULL characters (e.g. \u0000 encoded as utf-8)
- Control characters (e.g. \u0001 encoded as utf-8)
- Undefined characters (e.g. \u2065 encoded as utf-8)
- Non-characters (e.g. \ufdd0 encoded as utf-8)
- Private use characters (e.g. \ue000 encoded as utf-8)
- Standalone combining characters (e.g. \u0305 encoded as utf-8).

Comment: You're unit-testing the JDK CharsetDecoder class?

Comment: I'm using the `CharsetDecoder` class within a class of my own. I just want to generate the stated output from `CharsetDecoder` to test how me class behaves.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the *unmappable character* condition is relevant for encoding tasks only.  Here, the 256 character is not defined for iso-8859-1:

```
public void testUnmappableCharacter() {
    CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("iso-8859-1").newEncoder();
    CharBuffer in = CharBuffer.wrap(new char[]{256});
    ByteBuffer out = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);
    CoderResult result = encoder.encode(in, out, false);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

For UTF-8 decoding, the only thing you'll be able to produce is a *malformed* condition since all illegal UTF-8 codepoints cannot be encoded.

Comment: "the unmappable character condition is relevant for encoding tasks only" - I wondered about this too. But if that's the case why add the `onUnmappableCharacter` method in the first place?

Comment: Right. So I assume there may exist some encodings for which some characters are not mappable to Unicode 4.0.  I don't think UTF-8 is such an encoding, though.